# complex norm inequality

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

For $z,w \in \mathbb{C}$ How to show the identity: $$2(|z|^n+|w|^n) \leq (|z+w|^n + |z-w|^n )? $$ for $n \geq 2$.
I tried induction, but can't I finish.

Comment: If $z=1$, $w=-1$, $n=1$, don't we get $4 \leq 2$?

Comment: sorry, for $n \geq 2$

Comment: If you divide by $|z|^n$ then you obtain
$$
2(1+|\frac{w}{z}|^n)\leq |1+\frac{w}{z}|^n+|1-\frac{w}{z}|^n
$$

so you need proof that 
$$
2(1+|z|^n)\leq |1+z|^n+|1-z|^n, \forall z\in \mathbb{C}
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is similar to parallelogram identity.

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
|z|^n + |w|^n &= <z,z>^{n/2} + <w,w>^{n/2}\\ &\leq (<z,z>+<w,w>)^{n/2}
\\&\leq \frac{1}{2^{n/2}}(<z+w,z+w>+<z-w,z-w>)^{n/2}\\&\leq 
\frac{2^{n/2-1}}{2^{n/2}}(<z+w,z+w>^{n/2}+<z-w,z-w>^{n/2}) = \frac{1}{2}|z+w| +\frac{1}{2} |z-w|
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}